# magento 1 query generated back tics are wrongly placed

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, query, grid-layout

I have an issue in Magento 1, where the **SQL query** that is getting generated has the **back tics wrongly placed**.

This is a piece of the code that helps to provide the collection to the grid layout.

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){

    $accountId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('testmodule/coupon_collection');


    if (Mage::helper('testmodulecoupon')->isMultiProgram()
        && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Test_module')
    ){
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('p'   => $collection->getTable('testmodule/account')),
            'main_table.program_id = p.program_id AND main_table.account_id = p.account_id',
            array()
        )->joinLeft(
            array('r'   => $collection->getTable('testmodule/program')),
            'main_table.program_id = r.program_id',
            array('status' => 'IF (main_table.program_id = 0, 1, IF(p.id AND r.use_coupon, 1, 0))')
        );
    } else {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('program_id', array('eq'=>0));
    }
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.account_id',$accountId);  

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

In the above code, this part of the line is generating the back tics wrongly.

```
array('status' => 'IF (main_table.program_id = 0, 1, IF(p.id AND r.use_coupon, 1, 0))')
```

This is part of SQL query that is generating.

```
(`IF (main_table`.`program_id = 0, 1, IF(p`.`id AND r`.`use_coupon, 1, 0))` = '1')
```

I was not able to find a proper solution to fix this. Can anyone help on this ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build that part of the query using `Zend_Db_Expr` object. This way should work correctly:

```
array('status' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IF (main_table.program_id = 0, 1, IF(p.id AND r.use_coupon, 1, 0))'))
```

Comment: Thanks HelgeB ! it worked without errors.

Comment: Great to here that it works for you. If the answer was helpful it would be nice if you would upvote and accept it. That way others would easier find the soution for similar problems.